# Reshape 3d matrix to 2d matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a 3d matrix (`n-by-m-by-t`) in MATLAB representing `n-by-m` measurements in a grid over a period of time. I would like to have a 2d matrix, where the spatial information is gone and only `n*m` measurements over time `t` are left (ie: `n*m-by-t`)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need the command [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

Say your initial matrix is (just for me to get some data):

```
a=rand(4,6,8);
```

Then, if the last two coordinates are spatial (time is 4, m is 6, n is 8) you use:

```
a=reshape(a,[4 48]);
```

and you end up with a 4x48 array.

If the first two are spatial and the last is time (m is 4, n is 6, time is 8) you use:

```
a=reshape(a,[24 8]);
```

and you end up with a 24x8 array.

This is a fast, O(1) operation (it just adjusts it header of what the shape of the data is). There are other ways of doing it, e.g. `a=a(:,:)` to condense the last two dimensions, but reshape is faster.

Answer (score 12):

Reshape is of course the standard solution to reshaping an array. (What else would they call it?) There are still a few tricks to uncover.

First of all, the simplest way to turn an array of size [n,m,p] into an array of size [n*m,p]?

```
B = reshape(A,n*m,p);
```

But better is this:

```
B = reshape(A,[],p);
```

If you leave one of the arguments to reshape empty, then reshape computes the size for you! Be careful, if you try this and the size of A does not conform, then you will get an error. Thus:

```
reshape(magic(3),[],2)
??? Error using ==> reshape
Product of known dimensions, 2, not divisible into total number of elements, 9.
```

Logically, we cannot create an array of with two columns from something that has 9 elements in it. I did put a function called [wreshape](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23974-wreshape) on the MATLAB Central exchange that would pad as necessary to do this operation with no error generated.

Of course, you can always use tricks like

```
B = A(:);
```

to create a vector directly from a matrix. This is equivalent to the form

```
B=reshape(A,[],1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution to this problem is to use nshape.m available from Rasmus Bro's N-Way Toolbox. That will allow you to reshape along a given mode, which is a little more tricky with the reshape command.

The toolbox is available at the following link:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1088-the-n-way-toolbox

There are some other excellent tools there to help with array manipulation as well.