# Extending 3d matrix to 2 dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 3d matrix in MATLAB (time x channel x trial) that I want to extend so that it is a 2D (time x channel) matrix of continuous data instead of data segmented into trials. The closest command I can find is 'reshape', but I am unsure how to properly use it.

Is reshape the best command to use? If so, can someone please provide me an example of how to use it in my situation?

Comment: I don't have Matlab at hand right now, so try the following: if your 3d matrix has dimensions m x n x p , then try `reshape(your_matrix, m*p , n)`.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256925/reshape-3d-matrix-to-2d-matrix) answer?

Comment: I did see that answer, thank you. I didn't quite understand the answer until you just restated it. This looks like it will work. Apologies for reasking the question.

Comment: Actually, @R.Schifini, I implemented the suggestion and it doesn't seem like it worked correctly. When I index into the matrix I do not get the same values. Can you think of anything I could be doing incorrectly? For example, if my matrix was 100 x 10 x 5, if I use reshape(matrix, 100*5, 10) The value for matrix(1,1,2) is different than the value for the reshapedMatrix(101,1). They should be the same.

Comment: Try `pmatrix = permute(matrix, [1 3 2]);` before you reshape.

Comment: @beaker - that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
x = reshape( x, [Ntime, Nchannel*Ntrial] );
```